# Mockito with Spring in multilayered dependence structure

Tags: java, spring, mockito

I use spring to AutoWired Beans in my project, and also I use mockito for test.

```
@Service
public class A {
    someMethod() { }
}

@Service
public class B {
    @Autowired
    A a;

    someMethod() {
        a.someMethod();
    }
}

@Service
public class C {
    @Autowired
    B b;

    someMethod() {
        b.someMethod();
    }
}
```

Now, I want to test class C, with a real Autowired B class, and an mock A class.
How can I do this?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Use constructor injection instead of field injection, and you can simply inject mocks as constructor arguments as you would with any other object.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, this construction,  test C but need A in B; not a good way for unittest.
Unittest is for test only one UNIT.
At last, i moved A in to B, maybe it's a better way for unittest.